# Laravel-5 return eloquent object when running MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I would like to know if it's possible to return a MySQL stored procedure call as an eloquent object.

The below call works fine for me, but `$result` always returns an array instead of the usual Eloquent object.

`$result = DB::select('call bookings_by_voucher()');`

Does anyone know how to return this as an object, so that I can use `->count()`, `->get()` etc.

Comment: I am wondering EXACTLY this. Unfortunately I have inherited a gigantic Piece of dung database that I cannot redo due to money / time constraints. Being able to do the above would simplify SO MUCH for me

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the array into a new instance of your eloquent object.

```
$booking = new Booking($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A late question, but if anyone else needs this:

```
Booking::fromQuery('call bookings_by_voucher()');
```

The only problem is you can't do further sql operations like where, limit, etc, since you can't manipulate a stored procedure directly, eg: you can't do "call bookings_by_voucher() where active = 1 limit 200". You can use laravel collection operations though.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections

Answer (score 0):

you can use eloquent **MODEL**. It return an object .

ex.

```
$user = app\ModelName::all()->count();
```

get(),count() and other *aggregate function* works with **Models**